# Exporting TensorFlow 2 model to OpenVino

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, openvino

I want to export (optimize) a TensorFlow 2 model to OpenVino.

The only documentation I found regards Tensorflow 1. When followed the instructions, the OpenVino model optimization failed to work with a tf2 model.

Comment: TensorFlow 2.x is not currently supported by the model optimizer (see [this forum thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/computer-vision/topic/827537)). According to the [Model Optimizer Developer Guide](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_Deep_Learning_Model_Optimizer_DevGuide.html), the latest release is compatible with 1.14.0.

Answer (score 2):

OpenVino Model Optimizer does not support Tensorflow 2.0 yet. 
But, you can use Tensorflow 1.14 freeze_graph.py to freeze a TF 2.0 model.
This frozen pb should be accepted by Model Optimizer.

Comment: Just trying to confirm here. With `tf.keras` in TensorFlow 2.0, when we do `model.save("your_directory"), it does generate a `.pb` file. Is it accepted by OpenVINO?